# Load local HTML content dynamically

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, dynamic

I have to code a little HTML page for a knowledgebase and I need some help. The concept I got is to have very much little files with a headline, the purpose, some keywords and a frame where the content linked in the keywords should load dynamically.

My problem is the dynamic content because I can’t use the `iframe` tag recursively and jQuery doesn’t work on local files.

Comment: host it on a server. ajax problem solved.

Comment: alternatively you'd have to combine all your files into one big file. use grunt or gulp for something like that. and voila.. you can just open it and don't even need to use ajax.

Comment: I don't have a choice I need to read local files
And I can choose between html/js/css and vba

Comment: then, as i said, use a task runner to compile all of them into one big file.

Comment: okay, I'll have a look at this, but I can't imagine how this could work

Comment: lets just say: it infact is possible to compile various ressources into one big html file that you can doubleclick and use but trust me if i say that such a thing requires experience with tools like grunt, gulp, broccoli, babel or similar.

Comment: I didn't know such a program like these..
So I don't have any expreience..

Comment: then try them. read their docs. choose the one that looks most promising to you. experiment. try new stuff. learn by doing it :D

Comment: yeah, i would but I don't have that much time :x
I'll do it with sharepoint list now, even if this isn't the best way for the end user

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to be working on a server. local file path or url provided won't work for you.

Comment: I can't because I don't have a server

Comment: you don't need to be on any dedicated server. You can either create your own server using node js or you can use brackets as your editor so that you can see live preview of you work on a local host and it will allow you operate everything you want to do using a server.

Comment: @DarkErectDeath if your problem is resolved can you close the problem